# java eclipse debug never enters certain mvc service classes

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, model-view-controller, service

I'm attempting to debug my java mvc web app with eclipse.  However, debug isn't entering my service class that is called from my controller.  I can debug up to the point that my controller is calling the method "getReportsService.getAppReportLinksFromIQ(appid)" but it never enters into the service class using F5 in eclipse. So all I see is the resulting 'nullPointerException' the results from whatever it didn't like in the method.

**controller code:**

```
try {
    reports = getReportsService.getAppReportLinksFromIQ(appid);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**service code**  NOTE: URL in call is not the real URL

```
@Service
public class GetReportsServiceImpl implements GetReportsService {

    @Override
    public String getAppIdFromIQ(String appId) {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        //Get encode Application ID

        String getAppIdUrl = "http://url" + appId;
        AppIdDTO response = restTemplate.getForObject(getAppIdUrl + "/1", AppIdDTO.class);
        return response.getId();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason I can see for that to happen is `getReportsService` is null. Otherwise, the execution should enter the method.

If that's not the case, Please see the stacktrace of NPE to find the exact line.

BTW I am assuming you meant `getAppIdFromIQ` not `getAppReportLinksFromIQ`

Comment: The stack trace doesn't show anything directly referencing code in my service class, but it is showing an httpconnect call which would result from the call in my class.  It's like my class is a ghost.

Comment: You answered clued me into something see my comment above. I give you credit for this.

Comment: glad that i could be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

Please re-check the calling method name in controller and method name in service class.
The method name should be same in both.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment made me take a closer look at something.  I had specified the following in my service class

```
GetReportsService getReportsService;
```

I changed to

```
@Resource private GetReportsService getReportsService;
```

This cured the problem.  Thanks